# can i change the state of property of objects inside an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the matched property of objects inside an array but my function don't success to accomplish it this is the function please help me to fix the problem :

```js
let state = [
  {id: 0, contents: 'Provider', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 1, contents: 'Provider', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 2, contents: 'selector', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 3, contents: 'selector', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 4, contents: 'useSelector()', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 5, contents: 'useSelector()', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 6, contents: 'useDispatch()', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 7, contents: 'useDispatch()', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 8, contents: 'Pure Function', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 9, contents: 'Pure Function', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 10, contents: 'react-redux', visible: false, matched: false}, 
  {id: 11, contents: 'react-redux', visible: false, matched: false}, 
]; 

const cardFlip = (id) => {
      let flipState = [...state];
      const cardID = id;
      flipState[cardID] = {...state[cardID], visible:true}
      
      const [index1, index2] = flipState.filter(card => card.visible).map(card => card.id);
      if (index2 !== undefined){
        const card1 = flipState[index1];
        const card2 = flipState[index2];
        if (card1.contents === card2.contents) {
          flipState[index1] = {...card1, matched: true}
          flipState[index2] = {...card2, matched: true}
        }
      } 

      return flipState                                                                                                     }
```

This is the result finally:

```
cardFlip(3)

(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 0, contents: 'Provider', visible: false, matched: false}
1: {id: 1, contents: 'Provider', visible: false, matched: false}
2: {id: 2, contents: 'selector', visible: false, matched: false}
3: {id: 3, contents: 'selector', visible: true, matched: false}
4: {id: 4, contents: 'useSelector()', visible: false, matched: false}
5: {id: 5, contents: 'useSelector()', visible: false, matched: false}
6: {id: 6, contents: 'useDispatch()', visible: false, matched: false}
7: {id: 7, contents: 'useDispatch()', visible: false, matched: false}
8: {id: 8, contents: 'Pure Function', visible: false, matched: false}
9: {id: 9, contents: 'Pure Function', visible: false, matched: false}
10: {id: 10, contents: 'react-redux', visible: false, matched: false}
11: {id: 11, contents: 'react-redux', visible: false, matched: false}]
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve, write down your steps

Answer (score 0):

to update one object with new Values try this,

```
function updateFieldsInOneObjectInTheArray(
  state,
  itemKey,
  newContents,
  newVisible,
  newMached
) {
  const newState = state;
  const id = state?.[itemKey]?.id;
  const contents = newContents || state?.[itemKey]?.contents;
  const visible = newVisible || state?.[itemKey]?.visible;
  const matched = newMached || state?.[itemKey]?.visible;

  const record = {
    id: id,
    contents: contents,
    visible: visible,
    matched: matched,
  };

  newState[itemKey] = record;
  return newState;
}
```

Comment: this is a part of application card game Thefirst step is to choose a card by id and make the visible property of this card true and the matched false and change the matched property from false to true when you find two successive cards have the same contents

Answer (score 0):

Every element inside `flipState` has the property visible set as false except for the one you change at the beginning of your function. Because of this, after doing `flipState.filter(card => card.visible)` it will return an array with a single element so this destructuring you're doing `const [index1, index2] = flipState.filter(card => card.visible).map(card => card.id);` will always return a value for `index1` and undefined for `index2` which means the if will always evaluate to false, meaning matched wont change for any element.

I'm not sure exactly what you intend to do but if you want this specific function to work you will have to have at least 2 elements with `visible` as true.